# Getting error when running Auto Instrumentation using OTEL for Java service

Tags: java, open-telemetry, open-telemetry-java

Getting the below when trying to instrument JAVA Services using JAVA OTEL AGENT
Error:

```
[otel.javaagent 2024-01-10 03:02:35:052 +0000] [OkHttp http://localhost:4317/...] WARN io.opentelemetry.exporter.internal.grpc.GrpcExporter - Failed to export spans. Server responded with gRPC status code 2. Error message: Failed to connect to localhost/127.0.0.1:4317
[otel.javaagent 2024-01-10 03:02:55:054 +0000] [OkHttp http://localhost:4317/...]
```

How can I disable the exporter?

Tried Following environment variable setup

```
ENV OTEL_AGENT_OPTS="-javaagent:/opentelemetry-javaagent.jar -Dotel.resource.attributes=service.name=schema -Dlogging.level.io.opentelemetry.exporter.logging.*=OFF -Dotel.metrics.exporter=none -Dotel.spans.exporter=none -Dotel.instrumentation.grpc.enabled=false"
```

But nothing worked.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Which exporters (logs, metrics, traces) do you want to disable? Why do you want to disable them?

Comment: metrics and logs mainly